# Plugin takes too long to launch applet in browser for IE 10 on 32 bit Windows OSs

Tags: java, security, firefox, applet, internet-explorer-10

I have a issue on Windows * 32 bit OS with Java plugins in IE 10 browser that Java plugins (or I should say, jp2launcher) takes too long to launch a java applet. I am using 8u45 Java version. Is there any issue with the latest (8u45) Java version on Windows 8 32 bit version with IE/FireFox (I didn't check for Chrome)?

Comment: *"(I didn't check for Chrome)"*  You won't need to do testing in Chrome soon.  They are withdrawing all support for applets.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem on jre "1.8.0_60" 32 bits/IE 11.0.18 W7 64 bits. Investigating...